# Root-theoretic formulation of characteristic polynomial

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra of rank $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $G$ denote the corresponding simple simply connected algebraic group. By Chevalley's Theorem, $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]^G$ is a polynomial algebra with generators $P_1,\cdots, P_n$ of degrees $d_1,\cdots, d_n$.

Even though the generators $P_i$ are not unique, sometimes there are nice choices. For instance, in type $A$, we can take the coefficient of the characteristic polynomial. Let us denote these invariant polynomials by $c_1,\cdots, c_n$.

Question: Are there analogues of these polynomials for general types? Said differently, can we give a purely root theoretic definition of the $c_i$'s, one which produces an invariant polynomial (of degree $d_i$) for every root system (of rank $n$)?

Note: Of course some choices/variants of the coefficient of characteristic polynomials also give us invariant polynomials in other classical types. But I'm looking for a construction that works uniformly for all types.

Comment: I may be too pessimistic, but I doubt that such a uniform construction exists even from the viewpoint of  traces of powers.  It may be instructive to compare the closely related algebras of Weyl group invariants.   It's also useful to consider previous MO discussions (search for `invariant polynomials [lie-algebras]'), including this one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182871/generators-of-invariant-polynomials-of-semisimple-lie-algebra